# Undetected Chromedriver suddenly started to get stuck in captchas

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, cloudflare, undetected-chromedriver

I wrote about 10 scrapper using undetected chromedriver. They were working all fine until i wanted to create a next one. I started working on it and suddenly i started geting timeouts. When i removed headless, i saw that the cloudflare waiting room that i passed with no struggle kept me in an infinate loop. After that it seems like all of my previous code also broke. Here is a part of the code :

```
def GetTotalPages(self):
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--head')
    # options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")

    with Chrome(options=options) as driver:
       
        driver.get("https://mangasehri.com/manga/?m_orderby=alphabet")

        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "pages")))
        Lastpage = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "pages").text
        Lastpage = int(Lastpage.split(" ")[1])
        print(Lastpage,"total pages")

    return Lastpage
```

I have tried switching to gecko driver, adding options, nothing seems to be working. Is there an update that has been relased for cloudflare thet blocks it ? Or just my ip got blocked ? if so, how can i get around this issue.

Comment: Even accessing manually _Sorry, you have been blocked You are unable to access mangasehri.com_

Comment: in browser i had to click "im not a robot" like 5 times.

Comment: i can acces to the site on normal chrome. when i tried adding headers, it says i got blocked by owner, when not, i get stuck in waiting room.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase)'s UC Mode as an alternative.

First `pip install -U seleniumbase`, and then run the following script with `python`: (The script bypasses a site protected by Cloudflare)

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

driver = Driver(uc=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
time.sleep(6)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Still not able to acces the site i gave in the question. But it fixed some of the scrappers i wrote previously. I was able to acces : https://webtoon-tr.com/ (one of the websites i wrote a scrapper previously) but the link in the question: https://mangasehri.com/ still cant pass cloudflare.